# What are the components of a Peltier cooler and what form factors can it be shaped to?

Tags: thermoelectricity

I am looking to build a cooling device of sorts, and reading about the different options it seems implementing the Peltier effect is the most logical way as it has no moving parts, doesn't require maintaining compressible gas and can be used for small appliances.

But when I'm looking at ready-made examples all I see is modules where there are two square ceramic plates adjoined by these cubic ("dice") thermoelectric material.

The resultant module is very shallow, and to me it seems like the heat would travel quite a small distance and thus the dissipation would occur close to the mass you're trying to cool.

Is it a requirement that the thermoelectric metal be this small? About the square shape of the modules I find – I suppose it's not a requirement and you may make it oblong (but non-flat shapes aren't often used, I suppose).

Comment: Re, "The resultant module is very shallow, and to me it seems like the heat would travel quite a small distance..." Yes. That is the main reason why Peltier effect devices are much less efficient than traditional heat pumps which have an "evaporator" and a "condenser" that can be located with a significant distance (and lots of insulation) between them. Peltier devices are used for cooling in applications where minimizing the size or maximizing the reliability are the highest priorities.

Comment: I agree with @SolomonSlow - increasing the distance would give less leakage by heat conduction but it would also increase the electrical resistivity and ohmic heating. And it would increase materials costs.

Comment: @Pieter I basically want to remove heat from a liquid. The temperature difference should be about -20° Celsius, and from what I saw a simple module can go from room temperature to well below freezing temperature. The issue is whether the amount of heat dissipated at the hot side could prove too much and too close for such an application, or if the liquid is enclosed by a well insulated container it shouldn't prove to be much of a problem?

Comment: It depends on the flux of heat you want to pump, also on the temperature on the warm side. Maybe a cooling flange is enough, maybe you need to cool the warm side with running water. Read the data sheet of the Peltier element, of cooling flanges, etc. Engineering problems...

Comment: @Pieter I'll have to look into that. I saw a video demonstrating a Peltier element with a thermal paste and a heat sink attached to the hot ceramic. But he had the cold ceramic cool down to -17° Celsius, so I don't know what would be the requirements for the level of cooling I'm looking at. As far as I understand the ceramics themselves don't take part in the electrical process, and basically just serve as heat transporters to the metallic dice (on the cold side) and from it (on the hot side). So basically one could just fabricate a non-flat ceramic with more surface area?

Comment: @Pieter Also, I forgot to ask, the metallic dice should be isolated from any contact with the liquid?

Comment: The active parts are not metals but $p$-type and $n$-type semiconductors. Difficult to make electrical connections to that can tolerate the thermal stresses. Flat elements are complicated enough, you won't be able to afford non-standard geometries. And typically, Peltier elements are sealed.

Comment: @Pieter The video I saw which demonstrated the Peltier module used one that was open at its sides so you could see the dice inside. From the diagram I saw the construction simply involves the p-type and n-type dice being interconnected with thin strips of copper, and everything is sandwiched between two thin plates of heat-conducting ceramic. The usage of a ceramic that is already shaped like a heat-sink on its non-flat side doesn't seem any more difficult? The idea is that it would increase the surface area to dissipate heat (and perhaps also absorb heat?) more quickly.